# Make alert reappear with slideUp AngularJs and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

my scenario is: 
I have a file uploader that users can only select some pre defined formats. The problem is, if the user selects a forbidden extension, I'd like to show an alert indicating that (s)he has selected an invalid file. The problem is, after I call slideUp and try to show the alert again, it never shows.

My js:

```
$('#testBtn').click(function(){
$(".alert").show();
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
   });
}, 5000);
});
```

Of course I'm not firing the event by a button, but by a 'wrongExtension' event on the uploader itself.

I'm using bootstrap, AngularJS and Jquery. Here is a fiddle simulating the problem : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bY34d/)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the opacity of the `.alert` element to `1` from `0` as it's set by `fadeTo`:

```
$(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
    $(this).css({'opacity': 1});
});
```

[Fork of your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/marcolepsy/4hRcL/)

Answer (score 1):

it's all about what the methods you use do:

show -> set `display: block`

hide -> set `display: none`

fadeTo -> set `opacity: 0`

Now, after clicking once, you have `display: none` and `opacity: 0` on `.alert`, both hiding the alert element. When clicking again, `display: block` is set via show(), but `opacity: 0` is still hiding the element. A possible quick solution would be to set the opacity after clicking:

```
$('#testBtn').click(function(){
    $(".alert").css('opacity', '1');
    $(".alert").show();

    window.setTimeout(function() {
        $(".alert").fadeTo(1500, 0).slideUp(500, function(){
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Best
Marc